# How do I use apply to quickly determine which column a rows features apply to?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have an obj `eps` which is a `list` and in that object are a bunch of column names: `[col1, col2, col3, ...]`. I also have a DataFrame with a column called `features`. In that column you will find a `list` that contains numbers: `[1,4,5,13,17,20, ...]`. What I want to do is use the `apply()` method to determine which column (in `eps`) the rows values are associated to. So, `row['features'] = [1,3,4,6]`; `eps[1] = col2`. Therefor `col2 = True`, else if the number in `features` is not associated with any column in `eps`, `col_n = False`.

Is there an easy way to do this with pandas apply method?

Here is some psuedo-code:

```
feats= []
for row in df["features"]:
    for i in range(len(eps)):
        if i in row:
            feats.append(True)
        else:
            feats.append(False)
```

This works, but it's very slow and I know that `.apply()` will speed this up drastically. I've already switched to `.iterrows()` but it's still not good enough. Please help!

The first 4 elements in `df['features']` could be:

```
[1,4,6,12,45,67]
[3,6,7,8,10,39,57,64,65]
[2,9,10,11,57,58,60,71,75]
[1,4,10,76,584]
```

Comment: Have you read the pandas docs? Can you share an example of your data, a [mcve]? The description of the task might also need some work, I'm not entirely sure I understand it.

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`features` is series of lists, so I think you can't avoid the loop. Give list comprehension a try to see if it helps on speed

```
eps_tfs = {col:[] for col in eps}
features = [i in l  for l in df['features'] for i in range(len(eps))]
n = 0
for b in features:
    if b == True:
        try:
            eps_tfs[eps[n]].append(True)
        except:
            n = 0
            eps_tfs[eps[n]].append(True)
    else:
        try:
            eps_tfs[eps[n]].append(False)
        except:
            n = 0
            eps_tfs[eps[n]].append(False)
    n += 1

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(eps_tfs)], axis=1)

Out[1007]:
[False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]
```

**Note**: my sample `eps` has length 19, so my output is length 76 as 4 rows of `df.features` multiplies 19 getting the list `feat` of 76 elements

Comment: Why do `feat[df['features']] = 1`, followed by `feat.astype(bool)`? Wouldn't just `feat[df['features']] = True` work?

Comment: @AMC:  I use `np.zeros`, so assign `True` will be casted  to `1` to the array.

Comment: This won't work on a large series quickly. I would still need to use a for loop. Please find out how to use apply. I'm trying to figure it out now.

Comment: I could be wrong. Give me a minute, my server is crashing due to how large `feat` is.

Comment: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: Nope. Not a better method. It's basically the same thing that I am already doing. It was a good try though!

Comment: ahhh. I thought `features` is series of integer. Turn out it is series of lists. Try list comprehension as I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the answer and gave you a check. It sped up my program by over 80%. Big thanks!

Comment: @Ravaal: it's great! I'm really glad to know it sped up your program that much :)